# jQuery Conditional Decimal Greater Than Comparison

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an odd issue that I'm not sure quite how to fix, but here it goes.

I've got a return from an AJAX query and this is how two parts are returned (and how they look in the preview panel):

```
id:1
paid: "158.40"
balance: "79.20"
```

So initially I had just tried the following (after noticing an issue):

```
if(item.balance > item.paid){
   var test = "balance greater than paid";
}else{
   var test = "balance is not";
}
```

But in the above case, it returns the first `test` meaning that somewhere, the it thinks that 79.20 is greater than 158.40, which is obviously not what I want.

So I tried this:

```
var paid = parseFloat(item.paid).toFixed(2);
var balance = parseFloat(item.balance).toFixed(2);
```

And just switch the first line of the above conditional statement to `if(balance > paid)` and it still did the same thing...

So I am at a loss, if anyone can help - I'd be very appreciative.

Comment: Are the variables `paid, balance` already defined /available in the scope?

Comment: `toFixed()` returns a number in string representation. Try removing it, that should work.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `toFixed` when comparing those values, because it just gives you another string, which it can't compare numerically in the way you're trying to compare. Just compare the outputs of `parseFloat`.

```js
var paid = "158.40";
var balance = "79.20";

$(".string").text(paid > balance);

paid = parseFloat("158.40");
balance = parseFloat("79.20");

$(".float").text(paid > balance);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

  String compare:
  <span class="string">

</span>
</div>

<div>
  Float compare:
  <span class="float">

</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use `Number()` to convert string to numbers first

```
if(Number(item.balance) > Number(item.paid)){
   var test = "balance greater than paid";
}else{
   var test = "balance is not";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it like below

```
var paid = parseFloat(item.paid);

var balance = parseFloat(item.balance);
```

Then compare it will take you into right condition

Above you are using toFixed which again returns string.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to [toFixed](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_number_methods.asp) method, it is returning a `String`, not a `Number`. Hence the comparison result is not expected. There is no need to call this method for your case. If you have concern on the precision, take a look on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript)

```js
var item = {
  id: 1,
  paid: "158.40",
  balance: "79.20"
};
var paid = parseFloat(item.paid);
var balance = parseFloat(item.balance);
console.log("paid=" + paid);
console.log("balance=" + balance);
console.log("paid>balance=" + (paid > balance));
```